# I'm getting a GnssLocationProvider: 'Wakelock acquired' followed by 'Wakelock released' logcat error on my android studio app

Tags: java, android, maps, wakelock

I'm trying to build an app and on the landing page google maps zooms in on your current location. This has been working on an emulator then suddenly stopped with the error messages. I then switched to an android phone and initially worked fine but now I'm getting a GnssLocationProvider: 'Wakelock acquired by send message' followed by 'Wakelock released by handle message' error, and can't find where to fix it, or if the code is the problem. This is the code:

```
package com.example.mappractise;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
```

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
LocationManager locationManager;
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }

    System.out.println("Getting to line 53");

    //check if network provide is enabled
    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                //get latitude
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                //get longitude
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                //instantiate the class LatLng
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                //instantiate the class, geocoder
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    String str = addressList.get(0).getLocality();
                    str += addressList.get(0).getCountryName()+",";
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15.2f));

                    int num = 0;
                    do {
                        System.out.println("Count : "+num);
                        System.out.println("Latitude : " + latitude);
                        System.out.println("Longitude : " + longitude);
                        System.out.println("Time : "+java.time.LocalTime.now());
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        num++;
                        if(num==11){
                            break;
                        }

                    } while (num<=10);
                System.out.println("Loop Finished");

                } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        });
    } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                //get latitude
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                //get longitude
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                //instantiate the class LatLng
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                //instantiate the class, geocoder
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    String str = addressList.get(0).getLocality();
                    str += addressList.get(0).getCountryName()+",";
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10.2f));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Error above line 129");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        });
    }


}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

and the logcat message:

2020-05-16 17:06:56.771 1926-1943/system_process I/GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@771350b)

2020-05-16 17:06:57.771 1926-2998/system_process I/GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@adf1fe8)

2020-05-16 17:06:57.772 1926-1943/system_process I/GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@adf1fe8)

Comment: If you see the log level of the messages, they're marked as a log level of "info" - these messages are _not warnings or errors_ and can hence be disregarded as these messages only log information.

Comment: Thanks, this helped, I just filtered these out

Comment: @hotspuds How did you disable them/filter them out?